# Show different tabs based on the link clicked

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajaxcontroltoolkit

**Scenario**

I would like to display a particular tab of an ajax tab-container control when different links are clicked on a different page.

To clarify: Links are on page1.aspx and the ajax tab-container is on page2.aspx.

All links redirect to page2.aspx only.

But I need to display different tabs (on page2.aspx) according to different links clicked on previous page(page1.aspx)".

**What I'm looking for**

I thought I could do something along the following lines of pseudo-code:

```
LinkButton lnk1 = (LinkButton)PreviousPage.FindControl("btnLink1");
if (lnk1.Click)
{
  TabContainer1.ActiveTab = tab1;
}
```

The idea being that if a certain link has been clicked than a specific tab should be displayed.

I would put this in the PageLoad event of page2.aspx.

How can I achieve server-side (c#)? Or do I need a client-side (Javascript) method for that?

**What I've tried**

I've tried using session variables as suggested in one of the answers, but the click events are not firing.

Here's how I store the variables on page1.aspx on click of each linkbutton.

```
 protected void editPosition_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["LinkSelection"] = "lnkPosition";
    }

 protected void editRoom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["LinkSelection"] = "lnkRoom";
    }
```

Then on PageLoad I do the checks on page2.aspx

```
 if (Session["LinkSelection"].ToString() == "lnkPosition")
   {
            TabContainer1.ActiveTab = PositionsTab;
   }

 if (Session["LinkSelection"].ToString() == "lnkRoom")
   {
            TabContainer1.ActiveTab = RoomsTab;
   }
```

The markup of the links is as follows:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="editPosition" runat="server" OnClick="editPosition_Click" 
     Text="Position" ClientIDMode="Static" ></asp:LinkButton>
<asp:LinkButton ID="editRoom" runat="server" Text="Room" OnClick="editRoom_Click" 
     ClientIDMode="Static" ></asp:LinkButton>
```

**Final edit**

I have solved my issue by using query string parameters, instead of session variables.

Comment: As per my understanding, based on the links, you want to display/hide tabs on different pages. so for that, You have to store your Link selection value on postback then based on that you have to display the different Tabs. To store the link selection, you can either use encrypted QueryString or Session varriable.

Comment: Thanks @Piyush. Perhaps my question wasn't clear. The url of each link is always the same, but the tabs of the ajax control need to be different.

Comment: you want the same, what I explain in abobe comment?

Comment: Links and Tabs are on same page or different?

Comment: if you see my answer then I give you two options, either Session variables or QueryString? but you edit to specify that, I didn't directly answer to you.

Comment: You're right. I've accepted your answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you have to try this.

At page1.aspx, When Click on link , you have to set link selection value in a variable

```
protected void lnkUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["LinkSelection"] = "lnkUser";
} 

protected void lnkCustomer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["LinkSelection"] = "lnkCustomer";
}
```

At page2.aspx, on `Page_Load` Event, you have to check the session varribale value and then based on that, you have to visible true/false the Ajax tab

```
if (Session["LinkSelection"] == "lnkUser")
 {
    //put your User tab Active/Enabled logic here 
 }
else if (Session["LinkSelection"] == "lnkCustomer")
 {
    //put your Customer tab Active/Enabled logic here
 }
```

Instead of using If else, you can also use Switch Case. This is the sample code. 
If you dont want to use Session variables then pass the value in querystring with page2.aspx such as `Response.Redirect("page2.aspx?LinkSelection=lnkUser")`. You can also send the encrypted querystring to page2 where you can decrypt it and process

Comment: Although your suggestion makes sense, my click_event handlers are never hit.

Comment: Can you show the code which is not working? Then I will help you to solve that

Comment: Your page1.aspx should have <asp:LinkButton ID="btnLink1" OnClick="btnLink1_Click" runat="server">Link 1</asp:LinkButton> and page1.aspx.cs file should have protected void btnLink1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

Comment: Do you mean buttons causing validation? Btw could it be the viewstatemode of the links?

Comment: Can you please add the ValidationGroup property to each linkbutton with different value? as like <asp:LinkButton ID="editPosition" runat="server" OnClick="editPosition_Click" 
        Text="Position" ClientIDMode="Static" ValidationGroup="Position" ></asp:LinkButton>

Comment: If you have any validation on the page which is not required on that "Position" link button, then it will skip the validation and hit the server side code. Validation hold server side code to execute until success

Comment: I see. It doesn't help in this case though.

Comment: If validation is not the case in this scenario, then please add you .aspx page full code, so that I can see why it is not working? Because I try your code on new .aspx page and it is working for me. Definitely, something is weirdin your .aspx page